# Accessing machines by name over VPN with Windows7

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I'm no longer able to access the machines on my windows network when connected to the VPN while using Windows 7. Everything worked fine with Vista. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with W7, but name resolution problems over VPN is often because auto-discovery mechanisms won't work with a routed VPN.

If your VPN is routed instead of bridged, you may have to set a different option in DHCP (or a VPN-integrated host configuration protocol) telling it the address of the name service for W7 than in Vista.